# Swift: Could not find member init for my NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am making a NSDictionary to hold data for a tableview. The tableview is like a contacts list, with contacts separated by first name and sorted alphabetically, so I am making a dictionary to hold these contacts. The dictionary is defined as `[String: [User]]()` where User is my own object.

However, when I check to see if there are any entries for the first letter in a user's first name, I get the compile error: `Could not find member init` on my code.

Here is my code:

```
var users = CurrentAccount.friends
var organizedUsers = [String: [User]]()

func organizeFriendsByFirstName() {
    for user in users {
        if let xc = organizedUsers["\(user.firstName!.substringToIndex(1))"] {

        } else {
            organizedUsers["\(user.firstName!.substringToIndex(1))"] = [user]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String is a first name? or is it a First Letter with an Array of the users whose names start with that letter? I ask because I think you are trying to index a UITableView with the small letters in the right to scroll fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error not have anything to do with your `NSDictionary`, sometimes the Swift compiler it's not accurate with its compile errors, see this nice article [Swift Compiler Diagnostics](http://oleb.net/blog/2015/08/swift-compiler-diagnostics/).

If you put outside the line `user.firstName!.substringToIndex(1)` this throws the compile error :

> Cannot invoke 'substringToIndex' with an argument list of type '(Int)'.

And it is the cause of your error, you can use the [`advance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) function to make indexes in an `String`, change your function  to the following:

```
func organizeFriendsByFirstName() {
    for user in users {

        if let xc = organizedUsers["\(user.firstName!.substringToIndex(advance(user.firstName!.startIndex, 1)))"] {

        } else {
           organizedUsers["\(user.firstName!.substringToIndex(advance(user.firstName!.startIndex, 1)))"] = [user]
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant you're welcome, if the asnwer solve your question please accept it to can help someone else.